# android.view.WindowLeaked after Camera Intent

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I'm developing an Android APP via Eclipse and I'm having some trouble finding what cause the following error:

I'm calling an ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent to open the camera and expecting an Image on result. So:

```java
Intent v_Intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
try 
{
    v_Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,   Uri.fromFile(createImageFile()));
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
    Builder v_Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupPageActivity.this);
    v_Builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    v_Builder.setTitle("Arquivo não Anexado");
    v_Builder.setMessage(R.string.cameraSaveErrorInfo).setNegativeButton("OK", null).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
v_Intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
GroupPageActivity.this.startActivityForResult(v_Intent, IMAGE_CAMERA_REQUEST_ATTACHMENT_CODE);
```

And expecting it here:

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int p_Code, int p_Result, Intent p_Intent)
    {
    if (p_Result != RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            switch (p_Code)
            {
             ...
            case IMAGE_CAMERA_REQUEST_ATTACHMENT_CODE:
                {
                    if (p_Intent != null)
                    {
                        Uri capturedImageUri = p_Intent.getData();
                        //capturedImageUri = g_ImageUri;
                        if (capturedImageUri != null)
                        {
                            m_ImageUriList.add(capturedImageUri);
                            new CallAddThumbnails().execute();
                        }
                        else {
                            Builder v_Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupPageActivity.this);
                            v_Builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                            v_Builder.setTitle("Arquivo não Anexado");
                            v_Builder.setMessage(R.string.cameraImageErrorInfo).setNegativeButton("OK", null).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Uri capturedImageUri = Uri.parse(g_CurrentPhotoPath);
                        m_ImageUriList.add(capturedImageUri);
                        new CallAddThumbnails().execute();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }    
        }
    }
```

I'm able to start the camera activity, take the photo, but, SOMETIMES, not always, I'm getting this:

```
Activity MyApp.GroupPageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40583060 that was originally added here
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity MyApp.GroupPageActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40583060 that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:294)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:184)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:127)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:455)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:272)
at MyApp.GroupPageActivity$CallAddThumbnails.onPreExecute(GroupPageActivity.java:628)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:422)
at MyApp.GroupPageActivity.onActivityResult(GroupPageActivity.java:416)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3975)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2628)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2235)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:999)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The call is on this GroupPageActivity. And I know for sure that, when it occurs, it crashes BEFORE the onActivityResult call.

Any thoughts?

PS.: I was getting another exception thrown here:

```
Private Phone m_UserPhone = ConfigurationController.GetActiveNotNull();
```

This is a member of the GroupPageActivity.

PS2.: I noticed that the debug connection from Eclipse to the device I'm debugging is terminated inside the camera activity right when I take the photo. When I confirm the photo taken, then it crashes.

Comment: What is on line 39 of DB.java?

Comment: It's a throw new RuntimeException() inside a Catch for a try that is only called on the initialization for set-up the database connection.
I DID put a breakpoint on it, and on the try, unsuccessfully it didn't stop there.

Comment: Could you post the DB.java file and point out where line 39 is that's causing the exception?

Comment: iRuth. I've edited the topic, because that exception you noticed was thrown when I instantiate a member of the activity. I moved the call to the onCreate and now the Exception and Place changed. But the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line and try once...

```
v_Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,   Uri.fromFile(createImageFile()));
```

This happens due to uri leaked exception...it's better not to pass uri to the intent for getting a file